# Zebra ZPL ^A in Zplviewer

Tags: zpl-ii

Trying to use ZPL code with ZPlViewer.  As noted from others it works with simple commands 
So below simple code should work  .But in this example even the   command ^A0 fails ?.

```
^XA^MCA^PR8^XZ

^XA

^DFR:TST.ZPL

^LH110,0

^FO0,60^FS^A0,30,20^FB250,1,0,C,0^FD{0}^FS

^FO5,120^A0,40,3

^XZ
```

Zplviewer   complains about line 5:

```
zplviewer.ParseException: Encountered "30" at line 5, column 15.
Was expecting one of:
    "^XZ" ...
    <C_MC> ...
```

etc

Any hints or is the ^A command not supported ?

Comment: The ^FS command seems misplaced.  ^FS is used to indicate the end of some input data (bar code data, text field data, etc.), but in your case there is no field ending.  Perhaps you meant to place the '^fs' after the TST.ZPL file name?

Comment: Tried with just the one line but still same result:^XA
^FO0,60^FS^A0,30,20^FB250,1,0,C,0^FD{0}^FS
^XZ
It now complains about it in line 2

Comment: Try removing the first ^FS altogether.  Doesn't seem to be serving any purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I tried this , actually removing all of it so the line was just ^XA
^A0,30,20
^XZ
but still the error persists in zplviewer.  On the other hand , this worked:^XA ^AN0,30,20 ^XS  but produced no useful output , as expected.  I seem to be unable to find any good documentation on the ^A command. I have looked in the Zebra Programming Guide but there are no clear examples

Comment: In Zebra Commands Vol 1 , the ^A command is explained with parameters, but there seems to be no explanation of ^A0 in that section? , although the command ^A0  is susbsequently used in serveral of the examples

Comment: The parameter immediately following the A is the font to be used.  Zebra printers ship with a default font called font '0'.  So, '^A0' means 'use font 0'.  Perhaps ZPLViewer does not support using font 0.